# What is this insect with scary antennae?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I encountered with this insect on the wet floor in Sri Lanka. Is it dangerous?

[image]

Comment: I see you edited your question, incorporating the *cerci* of my answer, to address the fact that the *antennae* was not a *antennae*... but now the question's title is a bit contradictory!

Comment: Yes I did it with intention to help someone who will search with the real name of that thing. (At first I didn't know it's called cerci before your answer.) I understand now its not going well with your answer however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the antennae of that insect are not scary at all!

In your image, the antennae are pointing down; those forceps-like structures pointing up are part of abdomen, and are called [cerci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cercus).

That insect (probably a male) is an [earwig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earwig), from the Order Dermaptera. In the image below, the antennae are at the left, while the abdomen and the cerci are at the right:

[image]

Narrowing down the the Genus of your specimen is more complicated, but here is a list of earwigs from Sri Lanka: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dermapterans_of_Sri_Lanka

Regarding the danger: earwigs are not dangerous. The cerci may be scary, but they normally are not capable of hurting a human. Also (and I hope you don't believe urban legends), they do not lay eggs in human ears: http://www.snopes.com/horrors/insects/bugear.asp